# Unknown Error in my code regarding calling a unit within if statements

Tags: java, netbeans

In my program it would ask you for an input and that input would give you a corresponding deduction, but my code keeps giving me the same output which is "Rate Deduction: 634.57"
Even though it should be giving me back a higher amount of deduction "Rate Deduction:1624.57" or "Rate Deduction:2655.72"

I apologize for my rusty English but thank you so much if you would be kind enough to help me.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Cp11bTaxActivityKedawenJ jr = new Cp11bTaxActivityKedawenJ();
        headerdisplay();
    }

    public static void headerdisplay() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Monthly Salary Tax Checker");
        Name();
        try
        {
            Salary();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        System.out.println("==============================================================");  
    }

    public static String Name() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputN;
        System.out.print("Input a name: ");
        inputN = br.readLine();
        return inputN;
    }

    public static double Salary() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.print("Input a salary: ");
        double inputS = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        TaxCheck(inputS);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void TaxCheck(Double salary) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        double totalSalary = salary;
        double salary1 = 15000.00;
        double salary2 = 20000.00;
        double salary3 = 25000.00;
        double salary4 = 30000.00;
        double salary5 = 35000.00;
        double deduction3 = 634.57;
        double deduction4 = 1624.57;
        double deduction5 = 2655.72;

        if (salary >= salary3)
        {
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: " + deduction3 + "");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction3;
            System.out.println("Total salary: " + totalSalary + "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
            System.out.println("Total salary: "+totalSalary+"");
        }

        again();

        if (salary >= salary4)
        {
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: " + deduction4 + "");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction4;
            System.out.println("Total salary: " + totalSalary + "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
            System.out.println("Total salary: " + totalSalary + "");
        }

        again();

        if (salary >= salary5)
        {
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: " + deduction5 + "");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction5;    
            System.out.println("Total salary: " + totalSalary + "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
            System.out.println("Total salary: " + totalSalary + "");
        }

        again();
    }

    public static void again() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Would you like to try again?:\n [Y] for Yes  [N] for No");
        String choice = br.readLine();
        if (choice.equals("Y"))
        {
            headerdisplay();
        }

        if (choice.equals("N"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using me! (^_^) Goodbye");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new here so i apologize once again if this question/post is too long or if it was bad that i pasted the whole code here

Comment: Pasting the whole code is better than giving us an incomplete picture.

Comment: The code is not in a class.  You didn't post the entire class.  This won't compile as posted.  I guess it's in Salary.  You don't follow the Java coding standards.  Your code is hard to read because of the style.  You could simplify the text UI.  Empty catch blocks are a very bad idea.  If anything happens you won't know.  Print the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //Cp11bTaxActivityKedawenJ jr = new Cp11bTaxActivityKedawenJ ();
    headerdisplay();
}
public static void headerdisplay () throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Monthly Salary Tax Checker");
    Name();
    try{
        Salary();
    }catch(IOException e){
    }
    System.out.println("==============================================================");
}
public static String Name()throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inputN;
    System.out.print("Input a name: ");
    inputN= br.readLine();
    return inputN;
}
public static double Salary()throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Input a salary: ");
    double inputS = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    TaxCheck (inputS);
    return 0;
}
public static void TaxCheck(Double salary)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    double totalSalary = salary;
    double salary1 = 15000.00;
    double salary2 = 20000.00;
    double salary3 = 25000.00;
    double salary4 = 30000.00;
    double salary5 = 35000.00;
    double deduction3 =  634.57;
    double deduction4 = 1624.57;
    double deduction5 = 2655.72;
  if (salary>=salary5){
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction5+"");
        totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction5;
        System.out.println("Total salary: "+totalSalary+"");
    }
    else if (salary>=salary4){
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction4+"");
        totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction4;
        System.out.println("Total salary: "+totalSalary+"");
    }
    else if (salary>=salary3){
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction3+"");
        totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction3;
        System.out.println("Total salary: "+totalSalary+"");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
        System.out.println("Total salary: "+totalSalary+"");
    }

    again();
}
public static void again() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Would you like to try again?:\n [Y] for Yes  [N] for No");
    String choice = br.readLine();
    if (choice.equals("Y")){
        headerdisplay();
    }
    if (choice.equals("N")){
        System.out.println("Thank you for using me! (^_^) Goodbye");
    }
}
```

Comment: As said even if i input 35000 it still give me the equivalent deduction as if i input 25000

Comment: i change my answer you need to flip the order, the if(salary>=salary5) has to be first and so on

Answer (score 0):

The code is not reachable for if blocks where you check against salary 4 and salary 5, as you are calling `again()` after if block where you check against salary 3.

Call `again()` method only at the end of `TaxCheck()` method like below.

Also, you should change the order of salary check from higher to lower i.e from salary 5 to salary 3.